# HEVC decoding using FFmpeg with error concealment

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hevc, libx265

I am doing a project where I have to implement slice loss in HEVC encoded bitstream and see the output video after decoding. I am seeing a strange green patch in decoded video(using ffmpeg/UHDcode) in place of lost slices. Is it some sort of concealment? How can I remove those green patch?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: `ffplay -ec 0 file.mkv` disables all form of error concealment.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to use a video quality metric on the concealed videos, and the green patch would give unreliable scores, as some packet losses are visually more visible than others. So, if there were no green color, and some slice copy thing in decoder, my work would have been done.